# In while loop, How to use $i value inside foreach in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 16):
foreach($baglanti->query('SELECT birim_fiyat  FROM depo WHERE depo_kodu = "civ_'.$i.'"' ) as $civ_[$i]);
$i++;
endwhile;
```

> $civ_[$i] = doesnt work;

I couldnt figure out how to use "$civ_[$i]" inside foreach in a while loop?

Please can someone help me about that?

I want to achieve that :

get each different datas in mysql and use them in javascript to calculate different values.

example in script:

```
civ_birim_fiyati_2 = <?php echo $civ_2['birim_fiyat'] ;?>;
myvalue = civ_birim_fiyati_2 *2 ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get only 16 rows from the query?

Comment: actually no..this is only 1 sample... I will do that for 200 and than stop loop if not exist..

Comment: Maybe if you explain better what you are trying to achieve, a solution could be suggested

Comment: I try to : get datas from "mysql" with a loop and than use each data separatly in javascript to calculate different values...

Comment: for example : civ_birim_fiyati_2 = <?php echo $civ_2['birim_fiyat'] ;?>

Comment: myvalue_2 = civ_birim_fiyati_2 * 5;

Comment: You have an [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67446513/edit) link under the question. If you use that everyone will see any additional information you add, where as a comment may easily be missed

Comment: I did it... but I wonder if you know how to use "$civ_[$i]" format in php ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the database do all the work. Replace your code with

```
$civ = $baglanti->query('SELECT birim_fiyat FROM depo WHERE depo_kodu BEWTWEEN 1 AND 16' );
```

Comment: and how can I get that value as "echo" ?

Comment: You can't use echo on arrays but you can use var_dump( $civ ) or print_r($civ)

Comment: civ_birim_fiyati_1            = <?php echo $civ_1['birim_fiyat'] ;?>;

Comment: civ_birim_fiyati_2            = <?php echo $civ_2['birim_fiyat'] ;?>;

Comment: Jeff, if you look closer, the key in the query is more than just the numeric in `$i` it is in fact `civ_1`